# Formulation in Prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg

I currently have the following problem, that I want to solve with Prolog. It's an easy example, that would be easy to solve in Java/C/whatever. My problem is that I believe to be too tied to Java's thinking to actually formulate the problem in a way that makes useof Prolog's logic power.

### The problem is..

I have a set of 6 arrows, either pointing left or right. Let's assume that they are in the following starting configuration:

```
->
<-
->
<-
->
<-
```

Now, I can switch two arrows as long as they are next to each other. My goal is to discover which sequence of actions will make the initial configuration of arrows turn into

```
<-
<-
<-
->
->
->
```

### My initial attempt at formulating the problem is..

```
right(arrow_a).
left(arrow_b).
right(arrow_c).
left(arrow_d).
right(arrow_e).
left(arrow_f).

atPosition(1, arrow_a).
atPosition(2, arrow_b).
atPosition(3, arrow_c).
atPosition(4, arrow_d).
atPosition(5, arrow_e).
atPosition(6, arrow_f).
```

This will tell Prolog what the initial configuration of the arrows are. But now how do I insert aditional logic in it? How to implement, for example, `switchArrows(Index)` ? Is it even correct stating the initial conditions like this, in Prolog? Won't it interfere later when I try to set, for example, that `arrow_a` is at position 6, `atPosition(6, arrow_a)` ?

Answer (score 7):

Your problem can be formulated as a sequence of transitions between configurations. First think about how you want to represent a single configuration. You could use a list to do this, for example [->,<-,->,<-,->,<-] to represent the initial configuration. A single move could be described with a relation step/2 that is used as step(State0, State) and describes the relation between two configurations that are "reachable" from each other by flipping two adjacent arrows. It will in general be nondeterministic. Your main predicate then describes a sequence of state transitions that lead to the desired target state from an initial state. Since you want to describe a list (of configurations), DCGs are a good fit:

```
solution(State0, Target) -->
    (    { State0 == Target } -> []
    ;    { step(State0, State1) },
         [State1],
         solution(State1, Target)
    ).
```

And then use iterative deepening to find a solution if one exists, as in:

```
?- length(Solution, _), phrase(solution([->,<-,->,<-,->,<-], [<-,<-,<-,->,->,->]), Solution).
```

The nice thing is that Prolog automatically backtracks once all sequences of a given length have been tried and the target state could not yet be reached. You only have to implement step/2 now and are done.

Answer (score 5):

Since a complete solution is posted already, here is mine:

```
solution(State0, Target) -->
    (    { State0 == Target } -> []
    ;    { step(State0, State1) },
         [State1],
         solution(State1, Target)
    ).

flip(->, <-).
flip(<-, ->).

step([], []).
step([A|Rest0], [A|Rest]) :- step(Rest0, Rest).
step([A0,A1|Rest], [B0,B1|Rest]) :- flip(A0, B0), flip(A1, B1).
```

Example query:

```
?- length(Solution, _), phrase(solution([->,<-,->,<-,->,<-], [<-,<-,<-,->,->,->]), Solution).
Solution = [[->, <-, ->, <-, <-, ->],
            [->, <-, ->, ->, ->, ->],
            [->, ->, <-, ->, ->, ->],
            [<-, <-, <-, ->, ->, ->]].
```

Since iterative deepening is used, we know that no shorter solution (less than 4 steps) is possible.

I also have a general comment on what you said:

> It's an easy example, that would be
>   easy to solve in Java/C/whatever. My
>   problem is that I believe to be too
>   tied to Java's thinking to actually
>   formulate the problem in a way that
>   makes useof Prolog's logic power.

Personally, I think this example is already much more than could be expected from a beginning, say, Java programmer. Please try to solve this problem in Java/C/whatever and see how far you get. In my experience, when students say they are "too tied to Java's thinking" etc., they cannot solve the problem in Java either. Prolog is different, but not *that* different that, if you had a clear idea of how to solve it in Java, could not translate it quite directly to Prolog. My solution uses the built-in search mechanism of Prolog, but you do not have to: You could implement the search yourself just as you would in Java.

Comment: Hm.. Interesting, how did you manage to escape checking for previous steps (to not to get into infinite loop), and how you managed to find the smallest solution first. I believe that is because different step'ing algorithm (compared to my solution)?

Comment: Ok, I've got about minimum length. This is because of length(Solution, _) makes it start from finding 1-step solution, then 2-steps and so on. Interesting!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try to digest it until I understand it. I've already implemented far more advanced algorithms in C/Python (Q learning / Neural nets / Pso).

Comment: Btw, seems like your algorithm doesn't do quite what it should, but probably only because I didn't describe very well the problem. The idea is switching any two adjacent arrows. That doesn't seem to happen from your line1 to line2 of the solution.

Comment: This is, there must be a conservation of number of left arrows and also a conservation of number of right arrows.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
solution(Begin, End, PrevSteps, [Step | Steps]) :-
    Step = step(Begin, State1),
    Step,
    forall(member(step(S, _), PrevSteps),
           State1 \= S
          ), % prevent loops
    (   State1 == End
    ->  Steps = []
    ;   solution(State1, End, [Step | PrevSteps], Steps)
    ).

rev(->,<-).
rev(<-,->).

step([X,Y|T], [XX,YY|T]) :- rev(X,XX), rev(Y, YY).
step([A,X,Y|T], [A,XX,YY|T]) :- rev(X,XX), rev(Y, YY).
step([A,B,X,Y|T], [A,B,XX,YY|T]) :- rev(X,XX), rev(Y, YY).
step([A,B,C,X,Y|T], [A,B,C,XX,YY|T]) :- rev(X,XX), rev(Y, YY).
step([A,B,C,D,X,Y], [A,B,C,D,XX,YY]) :- rev(X,XX), rev(Y, YY).


run :-
    solution([->,<-,->,<-,->,<-], [<-,<-,<-,->,->,->],[],Steps),
    !,
    forall(member(Step,Steps),writeln(Step)).
```

It finds only first solution of all possible, though I suppose the solution found is not optimal, but rather first working one.

Comment: His question looks like a homework problem to me.  It may have been slightly inappropriate to write out the whole solution for him instead of just helping him get started.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to transform mat's code to mercury:

```
:- module arrows.

:- interface.

:- import_module io.

:- pred main(io, io).
:- mode main(di, uo) is cc_multi.

:- implementation.

:- import_module list, io, int.

:- type arrow ---> (->); (<-).

:- mode solution(in, in, in, in, out, in) is cc_nondet.
solution(State0, Target, MaxDepth, CurrentDepth) -->
    {CurrentDepth =< MaxDepth},
    (    { State0 = Target } -> []
    ;    { step(State0, State1) },
         [State1],
         solution(State1, Target, MaxDepth, CurrentDepth + 1)
    ).

flip(->, <-).
flip(<-, ->).

step([], []).
step([A|Rest0], [A|Rest]) :- step(Rest0, Rest).
step([A0,A1|Rest], [B0,B1|Rest]) :- flip(A0, B0), flip(A1, B1).

main -->
    (({
    member(N, 1..10),
        solution([->,<-,->,<-,->,<-], [<-,<-,<-,->,->,->], N, 0, Solution, [])
    }) 
    -> print(Solution)
    ; print("No solutions")
    ).
```

Compiling with 
mmc --infer-all arrows.m
to infer signatures & determinism